# ImageFileForm not binded with input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dropzone.js

I'm currently working in .Net Core MVC project and I want to post an image using `dropzone.min` library, so first, I create View Model:

```
public class TestAssetViewModel
{

    public string? FileName { get; set; }

    public string? FileUri { get; set; }

    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

}
```

**View:**

```
<form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input asp-for="ImageFile" accept="image/*">
  </div>
  <div class="dz-message needsclick">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <i class="display-4 text-muted bx bx-cloud-upload"></i>
    </div>
    <h5>Drop files here or click to upload.</h5>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ImageFile")] TestAssetViewModel model)
    {
        var wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        ...
    }
```

The problem is the `ImageFile` property is not bound to the view model property; the controller is just receiving it as null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work without dropzone.js? If so, you might look at what dropzone.js is doing under the hood to break it. Something is does [may be breaking your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815724).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue without `dropzone.min` as you haven't share much details about it. Its working fine and seding the files as expeected. I think your `dropzone.min` reference is causing the issue. Please check if your configuration for `dropzone.min` is correct.

Here is the way, I have tired to simulate the issue:

Model:

```
public class TestAssetViewModel
    {

        public string? FileName { get; set; }

        public string? FileUri { get; set; }

        public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public class ImageNotBindController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;


        public ImageNotBindController(IWebHostEnvironment environment, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _hostEnvironment = environment;
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ImageFile")] TestAssetViewModel model)
        {
            var wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            return Ok();

        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.TestAssetViewModel

<form asp-controller="ImageNotBind" asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input asp-for="ImageFile" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" accept="image/*">
       
    </div>
    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <i class="display-4 text-muted bx bx-cloud-upload"></i>
        </div>
        <h5>Drop files here or click to upload.</h5>
       
    </div>
</form>
```

**Note:** I have just added this Javascript Snippet `onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();"` to upload autometically.

Output:
[image]

In addition, I would recommend you to check [setup](https://docs.dropzone.dev/getting-started/setup) and [installation](https://docs.dropzone.dev/getting-started/setup) configuration guideline for [`dropzone.min`](https://docs.dropzone.dev/getting-started/setup)