# How to use Dropzone with autoProcessQueue set to false in .net8

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, dropzone.js

I want to use Dropzone in .net8 MVC project with autoProcessQueue option set to false.

I'm trying with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815724/how-to-integrate-dropzone-js-with-asp-net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com).

The problem is that controller isn't receive files. This only happen if autoProcessQueue is false. Otherwise it receive the file.

The code is this:

HTML

```
 <form asp-action="ProcessImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
     <div class="form-group form-actions">
         <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-4">
             <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Upload</button>
         </div>
     </div>
     <span class="text-danger" id="error-message"></span>
 </form>
```

JQuery

```
function myParamName() {
    console.log("executed");
    return "ModelImages";
}
let myDropzone;
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
    paramName: myParamName,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFilesize: 5242880, // Bytes
    maxFiles: 5,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drag and drop the images. Max 5 images of 5Mb each.",
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove",
    init: function () {
        console.log("active");
        myDropzone = this;

        $("#submit").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();        
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
    },
    accept: function (file, done) {
        console.log({ myDropzone });
        done();
    }
}
```

And Controller method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessImages([FromForm] List<IFormFile> ModelImages)
```

Only if autoProcessQueue is true `ModelImages` have a file.